# How can I add a package to dockerized Vue app?

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm, vue-chartjs

I have a problem with installing new packages to my Vue (version 3.7.0) project which is run in Docker container. I have `package.json` file to store dependencies and install with npm. For example I enter running container and try to install `vue-chartjs` linked below:

https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#introduction

```
npm install vue-chartjs chart.js --save
```

And there is an error in the browser:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js'
```

And in console:

```
+ chart.js@3.6.2
+ vue-chartjs@3.5.1
added 4 packages from 38 contributors, removed 68 packages and audited 1498 packages in 17.03s

86 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 19 vulnerabilities (9 moderate, 10 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Every time I try to install new packages, same situation happens. How can I avoid that?
Removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` + `npm install` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `docker-compose`, try to run the following command:

```
docker-compose exec <container_name> npm install vue-chartjs chart.js --save
```

If not, then use `docker exec` command and specify the name of running container. Example:

```
docker exec -d <container_name> npm install vue-chartjs chart.js --save
```